# Adicionar ponto na numeração do título e adicionar numeração no sub título da lista ordenada

Tags: html, css

Gostaria de saber onde estou errando no meu código css, pois estou tentando colocar um ponto no título da lista ordenada, exemplo:

1. Título

E também adicionar sub título para o mesmo:

1. Título

   1.1 Sub Título

Porém quando vou ver o teste, ele não está adicionando o ponto na numeração do Título, ficando assim:

1 Título

Onde o sub título funciona normal.

Código Css:

```
 ol {
        counter-reset: section;               
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    li::before {
        counter-increment: section;            
        content: counters(section, ".") " "; 
    }

    .custom-counter {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    .custom-counter li {
        counter-increment: step-counter;
    }

    .custom-counter li::before {
        content: counter(step-counter)'.';
        margin-right: 5px;
    }
```

Código HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-50" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
        <textarea required="" type="text" class="form-control" name="comentarios">
        <ol class="custom-counter">
                <li><b>RESUMO DE ATIVIDADES</b></li>
                <li><b>COMENTÁRIOS</b></li>
        </ol>
        </textarea>
</div>
```

Lembrando que, não possui um subtitulo no código acima pois estou trabalhando com CKEditor, onde após eu dar uma quebra de linha no título dentro do editor de texto, ele adiciona automaticamente um sub titulo

Imagem de exemplo:
[image: Imagem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tem que "iniciar" o `Counter` em todo o `<ol>`, e remover o valor default da Lista Ordenada. Depois no `<li>` vc faz o incremento do `Counter` no `Content` da lista

Basicamente só **removi essas duas classes** `.custom-counter li` e `.custom-counter li::before`  do seu CSS e já funcionou.

> Deixei os comentário no código do CSS

**Veja o exemplo.** (apenas removi o `textarea` do seu código para ficar mais fácil de ver)

```css
ol {
    counter-reset: section;  /* valor da inicial 1 */             
    list-style-type: none;   /* remove o valor default da <ol> */ 
}

li::before {
    counter-increment: section; /* inicia uma nova contagem com o valor 1 */          
    content: counters(section, ".") " ";  /* coloca antes do 1 o valor do pai */
}

.custom-counter {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-sm-50 " style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
    <!-- <textarea required="" type="text" class="form-control" name="comentarios"> -->
    <ol class="custom-counter">
        <li><b>RESUMO DE ATIVIDADES</b>
            <ol class="custom-counter">
                <li><b>SUB ATIVIDADES</b></li>
                <li><b>SUB ATIVIDADES</b></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li><b>COMENTÁRIOS</b>
            <ol class="custom-counter">
                <li><b>SUB COMENTÁRIOS</b></li>
                <li><b>SUB COMENTÁRIOS</b></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <!-- </textarea> -->
</div>
```

Aqui vc pode ler mais sobre o `Counter` https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters

Comment: Realmente funcionou, o problema é que ao mandar para o CKEditor, ele retira o ponto, exemplo (1. Teste para 1 Teste).

Comment: Nesse caso não tenho muito como ajudar. Vc pode tentar pegar o valor de um atributo *data* e colocar na frente.  Tipo assim `content: counters(section) attr(data-ponto);` e na tag li `<li data-ponto=".">` Testa e depois me fala se deu certo nunca tentei dessa forma rss mas pode dar certo...